# Run combiner on multiple measures with Python SDK?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

I'm struggling to find a real world example on how to use google cloud dataflow combiners to run a common ETL tasl which aggregates records on multiple keys (e.g. Date, Location) and sums values over different measures (e.g. GrossValue, NetValue, Quantity). I can only find examples with a typical Key/Value (e.g. Day/Value) aggregation. Any hints on how this is done with the Python SDK would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure I understand your question. Do you have separate elements you are trying to join the data together for, in which case you may wish to use [CoGroupByKey](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/af02b8c32baa80365a0605d3e94e0b10ded369ff/sdks/python/apache_beam/runners/direct/consumer_tracking_pipeline_visitor_test.py)? Or does a single element have multiple fields?

Hope some of this info helps,

I would suggest looking at [windowing](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/model/windowing), which will allow you to subdivide a PCollection according to the timestamps of its individual elements. If you want to see all the events for particular day this may be useful. Python [examples of windowing](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/python/apache_beam/transforms/window_test.py). You may want to window across a days worth of data. This [link](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/model/group-by-key) is useful as well to understand how you can use GroupByKey in different ways,

Another option is to determine what date your elements belongs to, and use a group by key to key it with "[location]*[date]*[other]". You may need to do something like this if you want to join the data based on multiple fields.

See this GroupByKey example, but change the key to use your [multiple fields concatenated](https://github.com/apache/beam/tree/master/sdks/python#counting-words-with-groupbykey).

Here is an [example for reducing with a custom combiner](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/python/apache_beam/examples/cookbook/combiners_test.py#L56). You can add logic here to do a custom aggregation for multiple different measurements.

Comment: Thanks for the rundown. You answered my question on the key, it will have to be concatenated, so the only missing piece is how to for example translate this for a combiner? With a GroupByKey I can only apply one aggregate function?

SELECT OrderDate, Location, MIN(Time), SUM(Value), SUM(Quantity)

Comment: Its more efficient to make a more complicated combine that does multiple calculations in the same function.

You could also store the pcollection into a python variable and apply two different combine steps on it. This is less efficient because it creates two shuffle steps.